# Definition for the "Yahwehism" tag, and how it relates to the "Judaism" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

So, after I [saw a question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/56695/how-did-the-samaritan-religion-created-from-israelitism) with the tag [yahwehism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahwehism) (tag now removed from that question by a moderator), I noticed that it both had only one question associated with it (who didn't create the tag, since their Reputation was too low to have that privilege), and it didn't have any tag usage information on it.

Doing a Google search, I found this Wikipedia page for "[Yahwism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahwism)", which states that it refers to the monolatristic precursor religion to Judaism. However, I've also heard the term used in Christian circles to refer to the monotheistic religion practiced by the ancient Hebrews prior to the destruction of the Temple by the Romans, as a way of distinguishing it from modern rabbinic Judaism, which evolved from one particular sub-sect of that faith (the Pharisees).

As such, I was considering proposing a tag usage of something like the following:

> This tag is for questions related to the monolatristic or monotheistic worship of Yahweh by the people of the ancient kingdoms of Judah and Israel/Samaria, prior to the destruction of the Temple and the Jewish Dispora.

I realized that this might potentially be controversial, though, and since I don't have the reputation to create new tags or to create tag synonyms, and since it appears that there might be multiple ways to spell the word, I figured it might be best to ask Meta for their opinion.

By comparison, the tag usage information of the [judaism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) says the following:

> Judaism is both a religion and an ethnic identity. Its religious component is predicated on the Hebrew Bible and other literatures, and is a monotheistic faith. As an ethnicity, Judaism embodies the culinary and literary cultures of Jews throughout history. Many Jews today are not religious, but see themselves as part of the Jewish people.

I can see, however, a few questions about the predecessor faiths to modern Judaism tagged under that question, so perhaps breaking the tag apart might solve things? Maybe even break it down further into a "Judaism" tag for questions about the modern Jewish religion, and "Jewish People" or "Jewish Culture" tag for questions about the ethnicity; there was a comment suggesting that we should avoid "overloaded" tags. The [judaism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) tag's only got about thirty questions, so it shouldn't be too hard to do manually.

Comment: Since it only had one question associated with it, and that has now been removed, do we actually need the tag?

Comment: @sempaiscuba That would also be a valid solution, if that's the consensus of the community. We do have tags for other related religions like Christianity or Judaism, though, and the ancient Hebrew religion was distinct from both.

Comment: As I recall, the fundamental principle of tags is to create tags only when they will help with searching.  If the term is known to be "overloaded"  - that is to say it is a homonym with two distinct meanings used in two distinct communities -(e.g. "However, I've also heard the term used in Christian circles") then I think there is a good chance that it will actually hinder searches.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I think that this tag might actually help with that, actually, by taking a degree of "overloading" away from the Judaism tag (which specifies monotheism in its religious component). Actually, I think I'll edit the question to include the tag usage info for the Judaism tag.

Comment: How many existing questions would this tag properly apply to?

Comment: @T.E.D. I can count about 12 or so of the questions currently tagged with "judaism". There might also be others under other tags.

Comment: Yeah, this seems rather unnecessary. We don't have enough questions to merit such a division of  pre/Rabbinic Judaism, even if that is the common definition of Yahwism. Which doesn't seem to be the case according to Wiki.